# How to fix .net core behind proxy on webhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am hosting a website on a web hosting provider, I believe they are using proxies and have given me a couple of proxies to use. I have tried puting them into my web.config as they advised using:

```
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://proxyaddress:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

However this alone didn't work, upon further investigation I kept this in my web.config and tried adding:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
   options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
                              ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

and

`app.UseForwardedHeaders();`

or

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

this again didn't really produce anything helpful and i'm still getting the same issue, I can't really find anything helpful.

I need to get past the proxy as I am using Azure Ad B2C with .Net Core 2.1 and its not working without the proxy, but works locally and on azures free app service.

[This is the error I keep getting everytime I try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksB5U.png)

[Sometimes I get this error instead, its similar but looks like its got less errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEXVI.png)

Comment: Did you also add `app.UseForwardedHeaders();`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Yes I have added and tried both app and from services

Comment: Just checking, as you hadn't shown that in your question. [ask]

Comment: It is in my question I just didn't add services one